# Azure Cross Repo Policies overrule repo local policies?

Tags: azure, azure-repos

I am wondering what happens if for the same branch thee are repository locally defined branch policies but also cross repo policies.

What policy is then applied?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policies are cumulative. And if the same policy is configured at multiple levels, the most specific (e.g. lowest level) wins.

Policies can be applied at a number op levels:

- Project
- All Repositories
- The Repository
- All Branches
- The branch folder
- The branch

And there are specific filters you can configure over the API to apply policies only when branches start with specific words for example.

A policy defined at the branch level will overrule the same type at any higher level.

Each thing you can enable in the UI: Reviewers, Pipeline etc are a specific policy type,

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just for my understanding I have one more question:
Assuming I have defined a cross repo policy for the default branch where I set the number of minimum reviewers and the allowed merge types. In addition I have defined a branch policy (for one repo and its default branch) with only the build validation enabled then the cross repo policy will not be applied at all, only the branch specific one.

As a consequence a pull request with the target being the default branch can be completed with only the build being green but no reviews done at all, correct?

Comment: No that's not what I'd expect. Each of the elements you mention is a policy in itself. The builds policy, the has been reviewed policy, the branch policy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. That is good news for my scenario that I have.

Comment: Each will be applied if enabled at any level. As far as I can tell Azure pipelines doesn't store 'not enabled', in that case it removes that policy type at that specific level, so the policy at a higher level will be the most specific.

Comment: Be sure to test :). You can do a lot of things through the 'az pipelines' cli.